# How can I add a page with posts to a menu with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new to Wordpress so sorry if this is a basic question. I looked on the internet but can't seem to find any answer.

I know how to add a page to a sub-menu with Wordpress. But what I want to do is to have a page that contains posts and not just static content. Can someone tell me how I can do this.

Comment: How are you doing this? Code or via the admin menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a page that list all your posts, you can tell Wordpress which page to use for displaying posts in Settings > Reading.

If you need to query some specific posts, you can create a template in your theme folder (file name didn't matter). You just put this at the head of the file to tell Wordpress that it's a template file and then can be selected in the page options :

```
/*
Template Name: My Custom template
*/
```

Then to query post, use [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function.

Example of use :

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task by admin section.

**Procedure:**

Go to **Settings -> Reading** in your wordpress admin area.

In that page, you will have the option choosing which page will display the list of posts in your site.

In "**Front page displays**" question, In  "**A static page (select below)**" option, you have 2 things namely "**Front Page**" and "**Posts Page**".

For "**Posts Page**" option, select a page from the page list to display all posts.

After saving the options, access the page that you selected for "**Posts Page**".

You can see the posts are displaying in that page with pagination.

[image: WP Reading Settings]

Comment: Downvoters please explain why my answer is downvoted? Can you prove I am wrong?